# How to find and eliminate memory leaks in LWJGL

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, console, lwjgl

I'm getting a few memory leak errors in a LWJGL project:

```
[LWJGL] 16 bytes leaked, thread 10 (Thread-0), address: 0x1D40000
    at org.lwjgl.system.Callback.create(Callback.java:133)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Callback.<init>(Callback.java:83)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWKeyCallback.<init>(GLFWKeyCallback.java:58)
    at InputHandeling.KeyboardHandler.<init>(KeyboardHandler.java:11)
    at Core.RenderThread.init(RenderThread.java:118)
    at Core.RenderThread.run(RenderThread.java:40)
[LWJGL] 1864 bytes leaked, thread 10 (Thread-0), address: 0x5D082700
    at org.lwjgl.system.ThreadLocalUtil.setEnv(ThreadLocalUtil.java:164)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL.setCapabilities(GL.java:242)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL.createCapabilities(GL.java:467)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL.createCapabilities(GL.java:321)
    at DisplayRenderEngine.DisplayManager.createDisplay(DisplayManager.java:71)
    at Core.RenderThread.init(RenderThread.java:118)
    at Core.RenderThread.run(RenderThread.java:40)
[LWJGL] 16 bytes leaked, thread 10 (Thread-0), address: 0x22B0000
    at org.lwjgl.system.Callback.create(Callback.java:133)
    at org.lwjgl.system.CallbackI.address(CallbackI.java:34)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GLDebugMessageCallback.create(GLDebugMessageCallback.java:54)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GLUtil.setupDebugMessageCallback(GLUtil.java:63)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GLUtil.setupDebugMessageCallback(GLUtil.java:30)
    at DisplayRenderEngine.DisplayManager.createDisplay(DisplayManager.java:72)
    at Core.RenderThread.init(RenderThread.java:118)
    at Core.RenderThread.run(RenderThread.java:40)
```

Is there a decent way to find out why these memory leaks happen? I'm not looking for you to fix me these errors but, rather, I'm looking for a general description for fixing these leaks?

Here is some more info(Provided by LWJGL) about my project if that helps:

```
[LWJGL] Version: 3.2.0 build 12
[LWJGL]      OS: Windows 7 v6.1
[LWJGL]     JRE: 1.8.0_151 amd64
[LWJGL]     JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM v25.151-b12 by Oracle Corporation
[LWJGL] Loading library (system): lwjgl
[LWJGL]     Found at: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjgluser\3.2.0-build-12\lwjgl.dll
[LWJGL]     Loaded from org.lwjgl.librarypath: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjgluser\3.2.0-build-12\lwjgl.dll
[LWJGL] MemoryUtil accessor: MemoryAccessorUnsafe
[LWJGL] MemoryUtil allocator: DebugAllocator
[LWJGL] Loading library: glfw
[LWJGL]     Found at: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjgluser\3.2.0-build-12\glfw.dll
[LWJGL]     Loaded from org.lwjgl.librarypath: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjgluser\3.2.0-build-12\glfw.dll
[LWJGL] Loading library (system): lwjgl_opengl
[LWJGL]     Found at: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjgluser\3.2.0-build-12\lwjgl_opengl.dll
[LWJGL]     Loaded from org.lwjgl.librarypath: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjgluser\3.2.0-build-12\lwjgl_opengl.dll
[LWJGL] Loading library: opengl32
[LWJGL]     opengl32.dll not found in org.lwjgl.librarypath=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjgluser\3.2.0-build-12
[LWJGL]     Loaded from system paths: C:\Windows\system32\opengl32.dll
[LWJGL] [GL] Using KHR_debug for error logging.
[LWJGL] [GL] Warning: A non-debug context may not produce any debug output.
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with freeing the callbacks. Could you explain how it's done? The other one is fixed though!

Comment: Thank you but I found out what I was doing wrong before... fixed it with your first explination!